# Found a typo in German survey banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey, survey-2018, typographical-error

I'm in Germany and my native language is German, so I was shown a German ad for the 2018 Developer Survey - and there's a typo on it.

I'm talking about [this banner](https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/14181341396003719327).

Just in case the link doesn't always show the same image *(no idea how this advertising stuff works under the hood)*, here's the actual image:

[image: german banner]

The correct text would be:

> Was glaubst du, wie entwick**elt** sich KI weiter?

Comment: "*How do you think will AI keep develop**er**ing?*" - I quite like that wording.

Comment: As German is my native language too, I can confirm that this banner is wrong.

Comment: Why is this banner even on german? If remember correctly, the version I answered was pure english?

Comment: Also, *Was glaubst du, wie sich KI weiterentwickelt?" would be the natural order of words. The second part is a dependent clause where the verb has to move to the end: https://easy-deutsch.de/satzbau/fragen/indirekte-fragen/

Comment: While obviously wrong, I like the funny interpretation of the wording. On one hand you can read it as how AI will develop (programmed by humans), but it may hint that the AI itself will be its own developer. But for a serious presentation, it should probably be fixed.

Comment: Maybe the AI doing the translation still needs some development too.

Comment: Just get an add blocker to block those poorly written advertisments, I recommend uBlock :P

Comment: It's wrong, but it is certainly wrong on purpose. Just a little play on words.

Comment: It could have happened intentionally, since the it is understandable anyway you write it.

Comment: *Was glaubst du, wie entwickelt sich KI weiter?* would be correct but it still sounds like a stupid translation. It does not sound good in German. *Was glaubst du, wie sich KI weiterentwickelt?* would be better IMO.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the heads up! While this was a short run last year - I've reminded our survey team (waited to close this to do so) to ensure this doesn't repeat in 2019 if the ad source is reused :)