# Stack Overflow Twitter account continues to have spelling problams

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, twitter

> **Edit:** I just saw [a new post](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1133383751168339969) from the twitter account and it has *exactly the same* spelling error.
>
> [image: Spelling problem with the same box but different image.]

---

I'm following the Stack Overflow Twitter account and saw [a tweet](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1131221969742045185) in my timeline featuring the below image:

[image: Twitter Ad]

I think that there is a spelling error in the orange box (right above the middle orange non-freehand circle), it should be cat**e**gory instead of cat**a**gory:

> Based on user reviews in the knowledge management cat**a**gory.

It's written correctly in the tweet text.

Comment: Actually, [they](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368716/typo-in-the-dev-isbored-so-jobs-banner) [have a history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362215/found-a-typo-in-german-survey-banner) of banner and advertisement typos

Comment: @window.document at least they are all marked completed. So this post has actually a chance of being responded to. :P

Comment: Good luck then! Also looks like you have tagged this question with the bug tag, but this tag _indicates a reproducible problem on the site_

Comment: @window.document Hm, you’re right. However I don’t think any other of the mandatory tags fits. Also the other linked requests use the bug tag too.

Comment: You're right that it's a typo, but given that Tweets can't be edited, there's nothing to be done about it other than declare it `status-wontfix` and move on with life.

Comment: I like how the typo in the title was corrected and reverted.

Comment: @Steven By the same person

Comment: Someone needs to take [responsibilty](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-australia-48210733) for these mistakes

Comment: Programm**a**rs make for bad spellars.

Comment: @Steven I added the title error intentionally and double-beep fixed it, but reverted the change after a comment from me.

Comment: @shafik the title is not a [problam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so) ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for flagging this. I really appreciate it as I'm an employee at Stack Overflow and worked on the G2 Crowd campaign you're referencing. The design aspect of the social posts that you point to in your question with the typo has been updated for future social posts on the topic.

Comment: Welcome Lori! May I suggest a slightly different wording? "The people responsible for our social media presence have been informed." I think that's what you meant to say.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just saw a new Twitter ad from Stack Overflow with proper text. Could you add a [meta-tag:status-completed] tag to my question to indicate that it is fixed? Thanks

Comment: Clearly we need to hire some llamas, @S.L.Barth